# HTML Page is coming blank but View source has all code

Tags: html, tapestry

I am using Tapestry 4.1 for the web development. When I go through my HTML pages. At times, some of the pages are coming blank and view source of all those pages has the source code :(.

This is not happening on specific pages but happening very randomly on any page and very frequently.

Not sure what could be the reason behind.

Any clue/help?

Thanks,
-Jack

Comment: A live link would probably be best

Comment: does this happen in all browsers or just some?

Comment: atleast some source code please

Answer (score 2):

Some things to check.

1. your HTTP headers (check out, say, LiveHttpHeaders for Firefox)
2. does the HTML code render in the broswer if loaded as a standalone file ?

If the answer to 2) is no, then I would recommend chopping the HTML up and searching for the offending fragments that render your HTML broken.

Answer (score 0):

I had this behavior in Firefox recently. Page was blank (server returned 403), but view source (Ctrl+U ) showed content. Turns out this content was cached. Some hard reloading fixed the discrepancy.